# Rails ordinalize in strftime pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ordinal

If I have this in an `.erb` file:

```
@shop.date_opened.strftimse('#%-d %b %Y')
```

How can I add the ordinal suffix to the day?  All the examples i've seen already have the day as a separate variable. In my case I don't, I just have the format pattern I want output.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for example:

```
time = Time.now
time.strftime("%a %b #{time.day.ordinalize}")
=> "Sat Jan 19th"
```

*Note that you will need activesupport inflection for this to work:*

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections'
```

Simply replace `time` by your `@shop.date_opened` and your time format pattern as you want.

Comment: all activesupport stuff should be required already if we're using rails. But yes, good note.